# Bootstrap 3 Tooltips or Popovers doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Django application with the front-end designed in Twitter Bootstrap 3. All of the my styling and JS is working fine including the modals, etc... But I cannot for the life of me get the tooltips of popovers to do anything....

I am not throwing any errors in Firebug.

Here is the order of my includes:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my an example call for the tooltip I took straight from the bootstrap site:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">Hover over me</a>
```

Anyone else have trouble with the 2 elements?

I am fairly certain it is something dumb I've done.

All other JS affects provided in Bootstrap 3 like the modals & tabs are working fine...

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `data-title` attribute, instead of just `title`?

Comment: Copied the example directly from the bootstrap site. Switched it to data-title but still nothing happening...

As a side note I have also removed all other JS in case there was some sort of weird conflict but that didn't help either.

Comment: Looks like a bug somewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/knownasilya/LhzwF/1/

Also see my comment on @steakchasers answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You just need to enable the tooltip via javascript:

```
$('some id or class that you add to the above a tag').tooltip()
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was dumb... =)

Comment: You shouldn't have to, since the data api is their first class api, and the javascript one is secondary. See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-data-attrs).

Comment: When I added the piece of JS it began to work, I also thought it wouldn't be needed but that definitely doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: From their docs: "For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt in. If you would like to use them just specify a selector option."

Answer (score 2):

Tooltips must be initialized with jQuery:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Opt-in functionality
For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.

One way to initialize all popovers on a page would be to select them by their data-toggle attribute:

```
    $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```