# Bootstrap popover and loading content with ajax and django

Tags: ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I know it has been given some answers but I will go for it :). As the title says i want to add popover bootstrap but with ajax loaded content. my html, but i want a Loading message to appear first and then the content.

```
<p class='entry' data-adjaxload = '/calendar/entry/1'>Title1</p>
<p class='entry' data-adjaxload = '/calendar/entry/2'>Title2</p>
<p class='entry' data-adjaxload = '/calendar/entry/3'>Title3</p>
```

my django view is the following

```
def entry_details(request, entry_id):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_id)

    args = dict(entry=entry, user=request.user)

    if request.is_ajax():
        return render_to_response('mycal/ajax/entry_details.html', args)
    else:
        entry_form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
        args.update(entry_form=entry_form)
        return render_to_response('mycal/entry_details.html', args)
```

Pretty simple. I am using the same view to either load html content via ajax in the popover, or a details page via normal get request

the ajax details page:

```
<div class="entry">
    <p>{{entry.title}}</p>
    <p>{{entry.date}}</p>
    <p>{{entry.customer}}</p>
</div>
```

and the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p.entry').each(function (){
        var i = $(this);            
        $(i).bind('mouseenter', function(){
            i.popover({
                html:True,
                title:i.html(),
                content:'Loading'
            }).popover('show');                    
            $.ajax({
                url:i.data('ajaxload'),
                dataType:'html',
                success:function (data){
                        i.popover({content:data}).popover('show');

                    }
            });
        });
        $(i).bind('mouseleave', function(){
            i.popover('hide');
        });
    });
});
```

But whilst it does run tha ajx and fetches the html, it won't load them onto the popover. How can I change that?

Comment: Since you've already declared `i` as `$(this)`, you need not encapsulate it in $ again.

Comment: Thank you.But still isn't solving my problem. But I removed $ from code as you suggested

Comment: Try removing `.popover('show')` since calling `popover({options})` will show the popover nonetheless.

Comment: all of them? removing it all of them didn't show the popup at all. I have no trigger option.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this? It will be easier to debug that way.

Comment: How can i make the django template in fiddle?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41626/discussion-between-apostolos-and-srvikram13)

Answer (score 3):

[**Just fiddled**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/bt997/) what you are looking for with popover content being updated dynamically using `echo/json`.

Just roll over the `p` element and wait for the 3 second delay.

If as you say, the data is being loaded properly then the only change needed is:

```
var popover = i.data('popover');
popover.options.content = data.text;    
i.popover('show');
```

Comment: I was doing that but i returned undefined...i.data('popover') gives me undefined on the code above. Added rel="popover" too but still undefined. Bootstrap 3 is what i am using. And as i saw in the generated code(developers console), no data-popover value is added in my p element

Comment: Oh so bootstrap 3 it is! In that case, are you initializing the tooltip class [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410887/bootstrap-3-tooltips-or-popovers-doesnt-work)?
If that doesn't work then remove the data-content attribute and everytime popolate the popover content using popover content options as `.popover({"content":"New Text goes here"});`

Comment: I do "initialize" the popover right when mouse enters the p element(first post)Or should i do $("p.entry").popover() before binding it with mouseenter

Comment: OK. [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/bt997/2/) that works with Bootstrap 3.0. The code is identical to what you've posted in your original post, except for the way the `success` handler of the AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you srvikram. Though when i change the content attribut in success the popover appears in a very "irrelevant" posistion comparing to the element that triggers it.

Comment: Check the `placement` property of the popover. It might be getting reset. If you've hosted your application somewhere would it be feasible to share a link?

Comment: i haven't phosted it yet, need to make sure it looks good before hosting it :). Sorry...but thanks a lot for trying!!