# Bootstrap tooltip doesn't appear, jquery scope?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After reading the Bootstrap 3 documentation, I also saw this post: [Bootstrap 3 Tooltips or Popovers doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410887/bootstrap-3-tooltips-or-popovers-doesnt-work)

I am using the javascript like this: `$(".tip").tooltip();` but I don't know if it's in scope since the bootstrap styling isn't being applied.  I have the following in a loop since I am generating html dynamically:

```
htmlStr+="<td><a href='#' class='tip' data-toggle='tooltip' " +
      "data-placement='right' title='" + finalExpr + "'>" + expr + 
              "</a>/td>";
```

that line is in a jquery each loop, which is in another each loop.  Then I close the table, then I use the javascript like this: `$(".tip").tooltip()`;

I encountered a similar situaton before and it was because I put the selector listener in the wrong spot.  To my understanding, you always want to put it after the html has been generated.  I am placing this selector function call after generating the table and right before replacing the div html in my single page application(via jquery .html) so I don't see why it's not working.  I also have the following imports:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"      
 href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-
 ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: One thing you need to note that you have included `jquery-ui.js` as well which has its own tooltip implementation. But since bs script comes after jq script it should be fine i guess. But see for any errors in the console may be some of your local js files are not loaded properly.

Comment: I called the tooltip method before replacing my container div with the html I generate.  Therefore jquery can't find the elements identified by my selector to call the tooltip function on, because it doesn't exist on the page yet, DUH!